# Centura - PDFCreator COM interop with different versions

Tags: pdf, sqlbase, guptateamdeveloper, centura

I need to call the latest version of PDFCreator from my Centura program(version 1.5.1). Is there any way to do this automation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific.  Do you mean you want to specifically use COM automation ( if you do, then PDFCreator COM interface is buggy ).  Other wise its just a printer driver , so are you using Gupta ReportBuilder and need a qrp converting? Have you tried Setting PDFCreator as the default Printer using the SalPrint* functions and just print using the SalPrint* functions.   Otherwise rather than repeat what someone-else has already , see this post in the Gupta forum : [Help with PDFCreator ( Gupta forum )](http://support.guptatechnologies.com/supportforum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=11517&p=43675&hilit=PDFCreator#p43675)

Comment: Yes, i want to use COM automation with the latest version of PDFCreator(2.5.3). Now i can only use the version 1.7.3 which is the last compatible version with my centura program.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you understand that the whole PDF workflow has changed between 1.7 and 2.5 - and using PDF COM has also, ( see [Migrating from PDFCreator 1.7 to 2.n](http://docs.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/2.3/en/pdfcreator/com-interface/user-manual/basics/workflow-comparsion-v1-7-v2/) , then you need to completely rebuild the COM interface between CTD and PDFCreator. 
From CTD1.5 Component menu --> ActiveX Wizard --> Select the Registered PDFCreator Library -->Select 'All' Classes --> Generate as 'Full' --> Save the generated file as an .apl and include in your .app mainline. All the new classes will be available to use.
As far as workflow , you need to read the whole PDFCreator documentation to establish how to use the newly generated classes / functions.
If you have already done all this , then you need to specify exactly what is the issue .